# snowflake -There was a problem updating your billing information. Please refresh the page and try again

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My trial period expired. I was trying add the credit card information. I tried multiple times and different browsers, get the same error.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we can't answer this question on Stack Overflow. Please contact Snowflake support, and give them more specifics. https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Submit-a-Support-Case-in-Snowflake-Lodge

Comment: Yup, try it again later. It doesn't work, contact Snowflake Support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

1. Try in a different browser
2. Clear cache/cookies and retry
3. Logout/Login and retry
4. Try again later

If none of them work for you, you can write to support@snowflake.com